# Nav in the page structure

Tags: html, structure

The right structure of my page is this:

```
1-This is the title
   1-Menu
   2-this is section 1
   3-this is section 2
```

So, this is how I write the code:

```
<h1>This is the title of the page</h1>
<nav> Menu </nav>
<section><h2>this is section 1</h2></section>
<section><h2>this is section 2</h2></section>
```

This is the structure. (to test it I use https://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/  and the extension html5 Outliner in Chrome with the same result)

```
1-This is the title
   1-Untitled Section
      1-this is section 1
      2-this is section 2
```

I do not understand what happens with the nav in the structure?
I tried to add a h2 inside the nav and hide it with css. Even when I do not like this solution because It is not the right structure and and I do not like to hide anything. I just try to test the outline :
`<nav> <h2 class="out"> Menu </h2></nav>`
and the result is:

```
1-This is the title
   1-Menu
      1-this is section 1
      2-this is section 2
```

How should I do the html to reflect the right structure and specially what is the right way to use the nav in this outline?

*(of course, inside the nav there is a ul with a lot of li. And inside the sections there are p, img and divs. I just simplify here to make it easy to explain)*

Comment: Is that normal that you have a "1" in your closing tag `</nav1>`?

Comment: @Simon: sorry, I have correct it. But this was not the problem